# How do I print the line only with the last occurrence of a regex?

Tags: command-line, regex, sed

I have a (large) file that has multiple occurrences of the expression `SCF Done` and I am (for now) only interested in the last of these lines. Currently I am using a piped command:

```
sed -n '/SCF Done/p' <filename> | sed '$!d'
```

I would like to replace that command by combining it somehow, but I was yet unable to do so. Specifically I want the `<filename>` to come last. Is there a way to do that?

While I would prefer a solution with sed, I am open to other command line tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, each sed command works from the same source data and they don't see each others changes. That isn't a problem when using the shell to pipe things around. If you don't want to use the shell to pipe output then you must use the hold buffer.

This should do what you want though:

```
 sed '/SCF Done/h;g;$!d' <filename>
```

This puts each match into the hold buffer (the `h`). Then, after it reads the entire file, it reads the hold buffer (the `g`) and prints only the last line (the `$!d`).

I think this could further be optimized if you could figure out how to get it to really replace the entire buffer on each mach but I left fixing that as an exercise for you. That will also allow you to get rid of the `;$!d` part.

Comment: Does that fix it? Replaced x with g.

Comment: Yes it does, thank you. I can now work on my exercise ;)

Answer (score -1):

To only print last line(s) pipe it through `tail -n num_lines`

For example to get only the last line

`sed -n '/SCF Done/p' <filename> | sed '$!d' | tail -n 1`

Comment: The command I use already produces only one line, piping it to tail is unnecessary since it is redundant. I would like to get rid of the pipe in the first place.

Comment: Can you give an example please. It's monday morning and my brain is still asleep.

Comment: I would like to get rid of piping or subshells, just combine the first sed command with the second.